# Store encrypted data in Ionic/Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, encryption, ionic-framework

I wanted to know of any way where we can store encrypted data for Cordova Apps?(common solution for both Android and iOS if possible)

It's mentioned on the official Cordova Documentation that there is nothing for encrypted storage feature right now. What options do I have for it right now?

I have already looked into PouchDb and CouchDb options. I am yet to figure out the encryption part for these databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [crypto-pouch](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/crypto-pouch)?

Comment: I didn't understand the Details part of the documentation much. Is it  explaining more about how to encrypt a single document inside the pouchdb database?

Comment: No, it encrypts all documents in your PouchDB database. If you are confused by the documentation (which I admit is a little dense, and seems to be more focused on Node.js), then you may want to look at [transform-pouch](https://github.com/nolanlawson/transform-pouch#example-encryption), which is a little more generic and which crypto-pouch is based on. You can supply your own encryption/decryption algorithm and hook it into transform-pouch.

Comment: I had more questions. 1. Does the encryption get persisted over a period of time (say if the cordova app is restarted again, will the pouchDB database be still remain encrypted?). 2. Why does the pouchDB database has to get encrypted first and then data has to get inserted into it? Why can't we insert the data and then encrypt it once we are done inserting in PouchDB? I saw this code in the test.js file which made me think about this.                 db.crypto('password').then(function () {
    return db.put({foo: 'bar'}, 'baz');
  }).then(function () {
    return db.get('baz');
  })

Comment: Answer 1) Yes, it will remain encrypted on disk, even after app restart. 2) The `db.crypto()` method just tells it what encryption to use when it starts receiving data. Perhaps a better name would be `db.setUpCrypto()`